# Using cypress behind proxy in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, proxy, continuous-integration, cypress

I have seen this on github but I was still not able to get `cypress` to configure/download correctly. In my jenkins pipeline I run `npm install` but this runs into a timeout because of the proxy. It downloads all other dependencies expect `cypress`.

What I did was download `cypress` and put the zip file in the project. I then run `sh "setCYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=cypress.zip npm i cypress"` but this still fails.

Part that fails in Jenkins pipeline:

```
   sh "npm config set proxy http://<proxy>"
   sh "npm config set registry http://<proxy>/"
   sh "setCYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=cypress.zip npm i cypress"
   sh "npm i"
   sh "npm run build
```

How can I have `npm i` run without download cypress. I currently cannot get passed this line `sh "setCYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=cypress.zip npm i cypress"` but I am also concerned `npm i` will still try to download cypress after `setCYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY` actually works

-------------------------Update One-----------------

I updated the `Jenkinsfile` to have `CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=cypress.zip npm i` but now I get the below error. `Cypress.zip` is in the project now but would really like to have it uploaded to Jenkins and just reference the file path within my Jenkinsfile.

I am not sure that is possible and the most simple solution is the one I am doing I think however it fails.

New error:

```
[view] Running shell script

+ CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=cypress.zip

+ npm install

npm WARN locking Error: EIO: i/o error, open '/home/jenkins/.npm/_locks/staging-c21b8f081f002623.lock'

npm WARN locking  /home/jenkins/.npm/_locks/staging-c21b8f081f002623.lock failed { Error: EIO: i/o error, open '/home/jenkins/.npm/_locks/staging-c21b8f081f002623.lock'

npm WARN locking   stack: 'Error: EIO: i/o error, open \'/home/jenkins/.npm/_locks/staging-c21b8f081f002623.lock\'',

npm WARN locking   errno: -5,

npm WARN locking   code: 'EIO',

npm WARN locking   syscall: 'open',

npm WARN locking   path: '/home/jenkins/.npm/_locks/staging-c21b8f081f002623.lock' }

npm ERR! path /home/jenkins/.npm/_locks/staging-c21b8f081f002623.lock

npm ERR! code EIO

npm ERR! errno -5

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! EIO: i/o error, open '/home/jenkins/.npm/_locks/staging-c21b8f081f002623.lock'

script returned exit code 251
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues on Windows environment. I placed cypress.zip into project's root folder.

```
set CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=cypress.zip
echo %CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY%
npm install cypress --save-dev
```

So installation did not work, because npm executable looks for cypress in `<your project folder>\node_modules\cypress\`

**Try to set CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY to absolute path.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're on linux, so the way to set an `environment variable` is `CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY='cypress.zip'` (`"set "` is only used on Windows)

Cypress will **not** try to download the binary if it's found on the system, *even* when running `npm install` again. By default Cypress downloads the binary to `~/.cache/Cypress`, so on subsequent builds Cypress will **not have to extract the zip** if this directory persists between builds.

The following should work:

```
CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY='cypress.zip` npm install
```

*no need to explicitly run `npm install cypress`*

Then, ensure the `~/.cache` directory is **saved after** and **restored before** `npm install` across builds.

#### or

Pre-extract the cypress.zip onto the build system to `/Cypress`, and use the following:

```
CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=0 npm install  ## Don't install the binary!
CYPRESS_RUN_BINARY='Cypress/Cypress'  ## this is the Cypress executable!
```

again, make sure `/Cypress` persists across builds

#### What if I don't cache `~/.cache` ?

Well, your build will still run, but take significantly longer as Cypress will have to extract its binary *on every build*. Read more here about [caching the binary in CI](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Caching-the-Cypress-Binary)

...

## Edit: For Question Update

You're still not setting environment variables correctly. **This will not work**:

```
CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY='cypress.zip'
npm install
```

You need to do:

```
CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY='cypress.zip' npm install
```

In *one line*.

**or**

```
export CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY='cypress.zip'
npm install
```

-> [Why here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205688/whats-the-difference-between-set-export-and-env-and-when-should-i-use-each)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response. In the bitbucket repo the `cypress.zip` was uploaded. In the Jenkinsfile I added `CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY='cypress.zip` but right after that is set I run `npm iinstall` which tries to download cypress and fails.

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool to deal with this problem:
https://github.com/tomasbjerre/dictator-cypress-example

You would need to clone this repository and publish your own `cypress-dictator` to your private npm repository:
https://github.com/tomasbjerre/dictator-cypress

It uses [dictator builder](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/dictator-builder) to, before `npm install`, copy platform specific zip-files to root of repository and make sure it is pointed at by `.npmrc`.

```
{
  "message": "Copy linux cypress to cypress.zip",
  "triggers": [
    {
      "runningOnPlatform": ["linux"]
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "copyFrom": "linux-x64.zip",
      "target": "cypress.zip"
    }
  ]
}
```