# How to set an environment variable to be used during "npm install"?

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, npm-install, cypress

Our coorporate network is very closed down, so a normal method of:

```
npm install cypress@3.4.1
```

Doesnt work since it is being blocked by a proxy, we need to provide the parameter `CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY`in the following way with the help of cross-env (since we have mainly Microsoft environments here).

```
cross-env CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY='\\localserver\cypress\3.4.1\cypress.zip' npm install cypress@3.4.1
```

This is easy to do on first install, but the problem is that everyone on the team needs to run this command. And I want it to be possible to just type `npm install` and they will get all requirements automatically. This is extra obvious when we want to update the cypress package, since the binary url needs to change each time.

I tried to add a `preinstall` script to my `package.json` like so:

```
 "scripts": {
    ...
    "preinstall": "cross-env CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY='\\localserver\cypress\3.4.1\cypress.zip'",
    ...
  },
```

But it seems like that environment variable set by cross-env is "gone" after `preinstall` is finished and `install` begins, since cypress tries and fails to download from the web. I am okay with it being temporary, but it needs to persist over the install-command. Also seen solutions with `.env` files but none of those have support for the `install` step as far as I can see.

My current solution is to run the entire cypress installation in the `preinstall` step, and it works but seems uneccessary to run a double install each time.

So, what I am asking for, is a way to let a developer just run the following commands on a brand new computer and be done.

```sh
git clone ...
cd ...
npm install
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I made a tool to solve this problem, see comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61556621/2477084

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Same situation on my side, except that I want to prevent the installation of cypress on the local machine.

Solved it by adding a `.npmrc` into the root of the project and adding to version control.

---

**Contents of .npmrc:**

`CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=0`

---

Since the environment variable is used on install time, the solution with `cross-env` was not possible, since one cannot be sure that `cross-env` has been already installed.

Let me know whether it helped or you have already another solution.

Comment: Of course that worked, and removes my dependency on cross-env. Out of curiosity, why don't you want the installation of the binaries on the local machine?

Comment: "scripts": {
    ...
 "preinstall": "npm install --no-package-lock cross-env run-script-os rxjs && npm run install:cypress",
    "install:cypress:linux": "cross-env NO_PROXY=true CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=https://internal.nexus.repo/cypress/4.4.1/cypress-4.4.1-linux-x64.zip npm install cypress@4.4.1 --save-exact",
    ...
  },  npm install,  its always using proxy (https_proxy) and fails. , even though its company internal repository i  added in no_proxy environment variable to bypass proxy.   any help ?

Comment: Perfect solution, works across different operating systems too

Comment: Note that adding env variable with name `MY_ENV` to .npmrc results in `process.env.npm_config_my_env`. So in this case it's going to be `process.env.npm_config_cypress_install_binary`. I guess cypress handles both cases so that's why it works. But other libraries may not.

Comment: with a newer npm version (>8?) this solution no longer seems to work unfortunately. Any other solutions like this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a tool that takes care of supplying the correct binary, depending on environment:

https://github.com/tomasbjerre/dictator-cypress

I have it internally at my company. When we need a new version of Cypress, we release a new version of this tool internally.

I add the tool as a `preinstall` script:

```json
...
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx dictator-cypress@0.0.28",
...
```

So that it runs when someone does `npm install`:

```sh
...
Copy linux cypress to cypress.zip
    Applying: copy linux-x64/cypress.zip to .
.npmrc should have reference to cypress binary
    Up to date: .npmrc should have lines
.gitignore should include the copied zip
    Up to date: .gitignore should have lines
...
```